# Proof that $x \neq x$ is false, in logic

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, axioms

We know from the reflexivity axiom that $x = x$ is true by definition.

So how do I show that $x \neq x$ is false? I know "intuitively" it's false but I don't know how to "show" it. I'm not sure what kind of truth table I need to build or if I need to state equality in some other way so I can work with it.

Do I need to reframe equality as the "if and only if" truth table?

Comment: What are your assumptions?

Comment: @Frpzzd That $x=x$ is true, the reflexivity axiom

Comment: No, I mean what set of axioms are you using?

Comment: Which rules you you have in your proof system, and what does "such-and-such is false" mean formally? Usually $x\ne y$ is considered an abbreviation for $\neg(x=y)$. Is what you really want to prove the formula $\neg\neg(x=x)$?

Comment: @Frpzzd I think it's first order logic? Just whatever basic logic is. It's just a question I thought of, I'm not a student or anything, so i'm not sure what framework this technically falls under.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Well we'd say $5=5$ is true, but $5=1, 5=2, 5=3, 5=4, 5=6, 5=7, ...$ are all false.

Comment: @user525966: That doesn't really ask any of the clarifying questions I asked.

Comment: @HenningMakholm My response makes clear what I'm asking. If I knew how to answer all the formalism stuff I likely wouldn't have this question to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends how you define $\neq$, but I will adopt the definition that $x\neq y$ iff $\neg(x= y)$, where $\neg$ negates a proposition. Since $p\to \neg(\neg p)$, the consequent being the falsity of $\neg p$, we're done. Note this argument only requires intuitionistic logic.

Comment: What other ways are there to define $\neq$? I am using this symbol to represent "not equal to"

Comment: @user525966 That was my way of teasing out the OP's assumptions, even though I'm probably right about what those are. For example, if they instead define $x=y$ as synonymous with $\neg(x\neq y)$ (i.e. $\neq$ becomes primitive, which is a bit of a long shot), then we're just trying to prove that $x\ne x$ is false from a Leibniz's law taking the form $\neg (x\neq x)$, which is a different but even easier proof.

Comment: @user525966 For example, in the context of set theory you could define $x≠y$ to mean $(\exists p\in x. \lnot( p\in y))\lor (\exists p\in y.\lnot (p\in x))$.

Comment: Or conceivably there could be some contexts in which one would define $x≠y$ to mean $\lVert x-y\rVert >0$. All sorts of things are possible.